# How to write a mongo query that queries an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database

Say I have a mongo database that stores the below data

```
String | Array
ID     | Data
100    | [Name: John, Age: 5]
100    | [Name: Lucy, Age: 5]
200    | [Name: Pete, Age: 5]
200    | [Name: Andy, Age: 5]
200    | [Name: Jimi, Age: 5]
300    | [Name: Raul, Age: 5]
```

How do I query the database to give me all the ID's and their existing Names within Data. I would expect the result to be showing only the two columns I need, as below:

```
{
    "ID" : "100", "Data" : [ "Name" : "John"]
    "ID" : "100", "Data" : [ "Name" : "Lucy"]
    "ID" : "200", "Data" : [ "Name" : "Pete"]
    "ID" : "200", "Data" : [ "Name" : "Andy"]
    "ID" : "200", "Data" : [ "Name" : "Jimi"]
    "ID" : "300", "Data" : [ "Name" : "Raul"]
}
```

Comment: Can you please show your input data in its original JSON format as well as the expected output?

Comment: That doesn't look lke an array and it's probably an object. You really should look at the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) first as this is a very common thing.

Comment: Why you have tagged sql in the question. I can't relate to sql to this question anywhere.

Comment: Apologies, removed SQL as initially the question was also involving SQL. Also edited the response to make it clear the Data object is an Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.collection_name.find(
   {},
   { "ID": 1, "Data.name": 1 }
)
```

It doesn't look like an array to me and it's probably an object.
You can use above query which will show the columns which are set to 1.

Comment: Thank you, this provides the result set I need :)